# How to delete duplicate solutions of this system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

I want to find vertices (has integer coordinates) of the triangle $ABC$ with the centorid is $G(1,1)$ and orthocenter is $H(3,3)$. I tried

```
a = {x1, y1};
g = {1, 1};
h = {3, 3};
b = {x2, y2};
c = {x3, y3};
Solve[{x1 + x2 + x3 == 3 g[[1]], 
  y1 + y2 + y3 == 3 g[[2]], (h - a).(c - b) == 0, (h - b).(c - a) == 
   0, -20 < x1 < 20, -20 < y1 < 20, -20 < x2 < 20, -20 < y2 < 20, 
  x2*y3 - x1*y3 + x1*y2 - y2*x3 + y1*x3 - y1*x2 != 0}, {x1, y1, x2, 
  y2, x3, y3}, Integers]
```

[image]

There are some duplicate triangles. How to delete this duplicate triangles?

Comment: You can `Thread[a + b + c == 3 g]` to relate the components of two separate lists more elegantly, not that this answer your question. Also `Thread[-20 < a < 20]`, and `Flatten[{a, b, c}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not certain I understand, but starting with `sols = Solve[ . . . ]` does this help?:

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}} /. sols;

Union[Sort /@ %]
```

> ```
> {{{-17, 7}, {7, -17}, {13, 13}},
>  {{-11, 3}, {7, -9}, {7, 9}},
>  {{-9, -3}, {3, 9}, {9, -3}},
>  {{-9, 7}, {3, -11}, {9, 7}},
>  {{-5, -5}, {1, 7}, {7, 1}},
>  {{-3, -9}, {-3, 9}, {9, 3}},
>  {{-3, 3}, {3, -3}, {3, 3}}}
> ```

Comment: This is a great little solution!  And calls attention to a useful case I'd never thought of, that `Union[myList]` returns `myList` as a "set".

Comment: @billc I am glad you found it of value.  :-)

Comment: I was looking for away to improve the output of `sols = Solve[Sin[x] == Cos[2 x] && 0 < x < 2 \[Pi], x]`.   You can simple add `// Union` !!