# Underlying Algorithms for List Manipulation Functions

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, performance-tuning, algorithm, implementation-details

Does anyone know, or know of a link for the underlying algorithms used for list manipulation functions?

Specifically:

- [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Union.html) with and without the [`SameTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameTest.html) option
- [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) with and without a *test* function.
- [`Gather`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Gather.html) with and without a *test* function
- [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html) with and without an *ordering function*

This question came about as there has been numerous questions that have asked about removing duplicates or some other list manipulation function. Some of the best answers often included usage of `GatherBy` due to the performance it offers (a few hundred times over `DeleteDuplicates` in some cases).

Related: usages of `GatherBy` and `Union`:
[Checking for duplicates in sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30290/checking-for-duplicates-in-sublists)  `GatherBy`
[Ordering function with recognition of duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/ordering-function-with-recognition-of-duplicates) `GatherBy`
[Gather list elements by labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28606/gather-list-elements-by-index/29551#29551) `GatherBy`
[Retrieving duplicates from nested list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6279/retrieving-duplicates-from-nested-list) `GatherBy`
[Delete duplicates in a list, depending on the sequence of numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/delete-duplicates-in-a-list-depending-on-the-sequence-of-numbers) `Union` 
[How to delete duplicate solutions of this system of equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23833/how-to-delete-duplicate-solutions-of-this-system-of-equations) `Union`

Comment: Hi Jonie; I'm glad to see you ask this.  I've taken the liberty to add a few specifics; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, You're more than welcome.

Comment: `Why You Do Not Usually Need to Know about Internals` http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html ;) But seriously, one should not have to know how a function works internally or what algorithms it uses to use it. All what one needs to know is the API. What is the input and what is the output and main purpose of the function. The complication in Mathematica is that there are different functions that seem to do similar things and hard to select which one. One should not have to do timings each time before selecting a function....

Comment: @Nasser That's not what really what this question is about.  This is about the computational complexities of the various functions and the algorithms they result from.  I intended to provide a thorough answer later tonight if I have time.

Comment: I have posted my unfinished answer below.  It is only a start and I haven't checked my work yet so errors may abound.  Nevertheless I wanted to show where I am going with this.

Comment: Oh dear; I still haven't finished my answer and you Accepted it anyway.  I'm sorry, I've been feeling a bit "burned out" for a couple of days.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I wasn't intending to rush you. The scope of this question is quite large and a lot of my original questions has already been answered in what you have so I accepted it. So please take your time.

Comment: Well, thanks for the Accept, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*This is an incomplete answer; I will continue it tomorrow.  Work In Progress: errors may abound.*

---

### Preamble <sub><sup><sub><sup>hat-tip to Leonid</sup></sub></sup></sub>

For the variations with custom test or ordering functions we can snoop on applications of that function to deduce the algorithm that is used.  In the case of the default methods we must rely on observed complexity and guesswork unless they are expressly described in the documentation or other official sources.

In every case the default method (without a *test* or *ordering* function) uses a well optimized routine.  Since the details of these methods are not directly observable and since I have no special knowledge of the implementation I shall reference them only in comparison to the customized forms and with supposition.

All of these experiments were conducted in *Mathematica* 7.  While I don't expect the underlying algorithms used by these functions to have changed in recent versions I cannot rule it out at present.

For all but `Sort`, which uses an *ordering* function rather than a *test* function we can use:

```
test = (Print[#, " -- ", #2]; Mod[#, 3] == Mod[#2, 3]) &;
```

I will make use of the following timing function:

```
timeAvg = 
  Function[func,
    Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}],
    HoldFirst];
```

I will use random numeric data on the assumption that the algorithm is universal; I have no specific reason to believe otherwise.

```
SeedRandom[2]
a = RandomInteger[99, 10]
```

> ```
> {92, 57, 22, 84, 63, 1, 81, 96, 19, 38}
> ```

### Split

I'll start with one not like the rest because it is easy to understand the behavior and will serve as an illustration for the other functions.

```
Split[a, test]
```

> 92 -- 57
>   57 -- 22
>   22 -- 84
>   84 -- 63
>   63 -- 1
>   1 -- 81
>   81 -- 96
>   96 -- 19
>   19 -- 38
>
> ```
> {{92}, {57}, {22}, {84, 63}, {1}, {81, 96}, {19}, {38}}
> ```

We see that straightforwardly every adjacent pair of elements is compared in order.
One would expect some overhead from a custom *test* function but the same **O(n)** complexity as default `Split`, and that is observed:

```
Table[{timeAvg@Split[#], timeAvg@Split[#, Equal]}&@RandomInteger[1,n], {n, 10^Range[0, 6]}];

ListLogPlot[time\[Transpose], Joined -> True,
  Ticks -> {Thread@{Range@7, "10"^Range[0, 6]}, Automatic},
  AxesLabel -> {"Length", "Seconds"}]
```

[image]

There is an additional component relative to the number of splits.  Observe:

```
d1 = RandomInteger[99, 5*^6];  (* lots of splits *)
d2 = Round@Clip[d1, {98, 99}]; (* few splits *)
Timing @ Length @ Split @ # & /@ {d1, d2}
```

> ```
> {{0.483, 4949976}, {0.125, 99485}}
> ```

### Union

Applying the same *test* to the same set with `Union`:

```
Union[a, SameTest -> test]
```

> 19 -- 1
>   22 -- 1
>   38 -- 1
>   57 -- 38
>   57 -- 1
>   63 -- 57
>   81 -- 57
>   84 -- 57
>   92 -- 57
>   92 -- 38
>   96 -- 57
>
> ```
> {1, 38, 57}
> ```

Here we see that the list is pre-sorted as testing starts with the small numbers: {1, 19, 22}.  Also, we see that comparisons are each time with one of three unique elements {1, 38, 57} (right column).  The algorithm appears to be:

1. Sort the list using the canonical ordering, and put the first element in a keep list.
2. Take the last keep list element (1) and compare it to subsequent elements (the left column) until *test* returns False.
3. Add the new unique element to the keep list (38) and compare it to subsequent elements from this element.
4. If in Step #3 a *test* returns False compare it to each prior element in the *keep* list; if it matches one continue with Step #3, else add to *keep* and start a new #3 with that element.
5. Stop when the last element is reached and compared (if necessary) to all elements of *keep*.

Some things result from this (supposed) algorithm.  One is that the number of comparisons is directly influenced by the number of unique elements (defined by *test*) there are.  Compare the output of these two lines:

```
Union[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, SameTest -> ((Print[#, " -- ", #2]; # == #2) &)]
```

> 1 -- 1
>   1 -- 1
>   1 -- 1
>   1 -- 1

```
Union[Range@5, SameTest -> ((Print[#, " -- ", #2]; # == #2) &)]
```

> 2 -- 1
>   3 -- 2
>   3 -- 1
>   4 -- 3
>   4 -- 2
>   4 -- 1
>   5 -- 4
>   5 -- 3
>   5 -- 2
>   5 -- 1

In the first case there are only `(n-1)` tests whereas in the second there are `n (n-1) / 2` tests performed.

With a limited number of unique elements using `SameTest` has roughly equal computational complexity to the default `Union` (though several times slower):

```
times1 = Table[
   {timeAvg @ Union[#], timeAvg @ Union[#, SameTest -> Equal]} &@RandomInteger[20, n],
   {n, 10^Range[0, 6]}];

ListLogPlot[times1\[Transpose], Joined -> True, 
 Ticks -> {Thread@{Range@7, "10"^Range[0, 6]}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Length", "Seconds"}]
```

[image]

With a fixed length but a different numbers of unique elements very different behavior emerges:

```
times2 = Table[
   {timeAvg @ Union[#], timeAvg @ Union[#, SameTest -> Equal]} &@
    RandomInteger[{1, n}, 1*^5],
   {n, 5^Range[0, 6]}];

ListLogPlot[times2\[Transpose], Joined -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Thread@{Range@7, "5"^Range[0, 6]}, Automatic}, Frame -> {1, 1, 0, 0}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Unique elements (max)", "Seconds"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Clearly a default `Union` uses other optimizations.  A hint at this optimization can be found on MathGroup in reference to the *old* way that `SameTest` worked and by inference the way that default Union still does:

> [[mg16113]](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Feb/msg00401.html)
>   The Union function sorts the elements before
>   comparing them, and compares only adjacent elements after sorting. 
>   This is done for reasons of efficiency.

So the default is akin to `Split` in this way, and in fact Carl Woll implemented the old-style `SameTest` in terms of `Split` in another MathGroup post: [[mg23309]](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2000/May/msg00012.html).  There is additional discussion there of complexity that is very pertinent to this topic.

### Gather

Our preliminary experiment once again:

```
Gather[a, test]
```

> 92 -- 57
>   92 -- 22
>   57 -- 22
>   92 -- 84
>   57 -- 84
>   92 -- 63
>   57 -- 63
>   92 -- 1
>   57 -- 1
>   22 -- 1
>   92 -- 81
>   57 -- 81
>   92 -- 96
>   57 -- 96
>   92 -- 19
>   57 -- 19
>   22 -- 19
>   92 -- 38
>
> ```
> {{92, 38}, {57, 84, 63, 81, 96}, {22, 1, 19}}
> ```

The list is not sorted and the first two elements receive the first *test*.  We see quite a few more applications of `test` this time compared to `Union` but that proves to be mere chance.

The same three "groups" are formed by the `Mod` function as with `Union`: there `1,38,57` in the right column; here `92,57,22` in the left.  The tests are no longer in canonical order as the list is not sorted but the same type of comparisons are made.

To show that the apparent difference in the number of *test* applications between `Gather` and `Union` is not significant we can run the test with many other sets

```
Module[{x, i, test2},
 test2 = (i++; Mod[#, 3] == Mod[#2, 3]) &;
 Table[
    x = RandomInteger[99, 10]; {
     i = 0; Union[x, SameTest -> test2]; i,
     i = 0; Gather[x, test2]; i
     } , {10000}
 ] // Pane /@ Histogram /@ Transpose[#] & // Row
]
```

[image]

Given the equal number of comparisons one might expect the performance of `Gather` and `Union` (with *test* functions) to track quite well, however there are some surprises.

With a limited number of groups the time complexity trends to the same degree as `Union` but the scales are surprising:

```
gtest[a_, b_] := a == b
times1 = Table[
   {timeAvg @ Gather[#], timeAvg @ Gather[#, gtest]} &@RandomInteger[20, n],
   {n, 10^Range[0, 6]}
  ];

ListLogPlot[times1\[Transpose], Joined -> True, 
 Ticks -> {Thread@{Range@7, "10"^Range[0, 6]}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Length", "Seconds"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

I have overlaid this graphic with the one for `Union` for easy comparison.  On this test with a limited number of unique elements (20) default and *test* `Union` were within an order of magnitude, but default and *test* `Gather` are nearly *five* orders of magnitude apart.  One might expect `Gather` with *test* to be slower than the equivalent `Union` lists must be built, however it is interesting to note that default `Gather` is an order of magnitude faster than default `Union` here.

For the test with a varying number of unique elements I had to abort at `5^5` as the function slowed down too greatly:

```
gtest[a_, b_] := a == b
times2 = Table[
  {timeAvg @ Gather[#], timeAvg @ Gather[#, gtest]} &@RandomInteger[{1, n}, 1*^5],
  {n, 5^Range[0, 5]}
 ];

ListLogPlot[times2\[Transpose], Joined -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Thread@{Range@7, "5"^Range[0, 6]}, Automatic}, Frame -> {1, 1, 0, 0}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Unique elements (max)", "Seconds"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

Again I have overlaid the result from the corresponding `Union` result.  Complexities here are harder to compare, and more testing is in order.

#### Automatic enhancements in `Gather`

You may have noticed that I used `gtest[a_, b_] := a == b` rather than merely `Equal` or even `# == #2 &` as the test.  This is because `Gather` has special handling built in to optimize such cases; this is normally a good thing but in this case it amounts to cheating.

- `Gather[x, Equal]` is apparently converted directly to `Gather[x]`.
- A symmetric pure function of the form `lhs == rhs &` or `lhs === rhs &` where `lhs` and `rhs` are identical except for the arguments is converted to `GatherBy`, i.e. `GatherBy[x, lhs &]`.

Examples supporting these assertions:

1. Timings are the same as `Gather[x]` for explicit use of `Equal` and `SameQ`:

   ```
   big = RandomInteger[5000, 10000];

   Gather[big]        // timeAvg
   Gather[big, Equal] // timeAvg
   Gather[big, SameQ] // timeAvg
   ```

   > 0.002624
   >
   > 0.002624
   >
   > 0.002616
2. Convertion to `GatherBy` (or internal equivalent) is directly observable using `Print` or `Sow:

   ```
   Gather[Range@5, Print[#] == Print[#2] &];
   ```

   > 1
   >   2
   >   3
   >   4
   >   5

   Note that each element is printed only *once* -- this is the behavior of `GatherBy` not a pairwise comparison!

---

Comment: First, where's the comparison between using `test` in `Split` vs. not using it? You only give timings for not using it. Also, if you haven't upgraded, yet, you should put in a caveat about using v7. To my real comment: I suspect that the elements are sorted in `Union` to ensure uniqueness, i.e. two different orderings of the same list always give the same union. This makes it useful in comparing two sets.

Comment: @rcollyer Patience my friend. :-)  Good point regarding v7  however; I'm guessing the algorithms are the same in later versions (as I believe they have good reason to be the way they are) but I can't be certain.  I'll return to this in a few hours.

Comment: I am being patient. You're supposed to have finished it by now ... where's the rest ... :) If you send me an email in the morning, I can run it for you on quite a few different versions, if you wish.

Comment: @rcollyer the 'useful' factor in comparing two sets is quite likely. The documentation page for both `Union` and `Complement` does state that they return a sorted list.

Comment: Also the algorithm of union does surprise me, as I was expecting more of a hash bucket approach which would be significantly faster in a large dataset (potentially a optimization for default).

Comment: Re: default `Union` I can't be sure that version 7 (what I use) is the same as what Dave Withoff described in the quote in my answer.  The defaults are hard to examine (black box) and I'm hardly well versed in low-level algorithms so I don't feel qualified to explore that further.  However, the hash-table approach is likely what default `Gather` is using and you see that it is faster than `Union` at least in some cases.  This answer still isn't done but I'll probably not make any major edits tonight.

Comment: That's one nice find on Gather for not doing a pairwise comparison - thoroughly explaining their performance.

Comment: @Jonie I must admit it came as a surprise to me too, assuming you mean the "symmetric function" case.  I've avoided `Gather` (with *test*) most of the time because I expected it to be slow; I see now that sometimes it is equivalent to `GatherBy`, but I'll continue to use the latter because it is shorter and more declarative (it does what it says rather than relying on hidden optimizations).  By the way I may not get around to continuing this answer today but I'll do it soon.

Comment: +1 for the attribution to Leonid for the invention of preambles

Comment: ...and for the rest of the post