# Selective deletion of nested list elements centred around a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, pattern-matching

I have a list which looks like:

```
test = {{0.01,3}, {0.001,3.1}, {0.002,3.2}, ..., {0.01,7}, {0.001,7.1}, {0.002,7.2}, ...,     
        {0.01,10}, {0.001,10.1}, {0.002,10.2}, ..., {0.01,13}, {0.001,13.1}, {0.002,13.2}}
```

What I would like to do is for every value of the second coordinate that is close to a centre value (near `3`, `7`, `10` or `13`) I only want to keep the ones (pairs) that have the smallest value of the first coordinate. After this transformation the list would become:

```
{{0.001,3.1}, {0.001,7.1}, {0.001,10.1}, {0.001,13.1}}
```

Note that when I have entered a break in the test list there is also a spacing in the 2nd coordinate values, so the list runs from say `3 - 3.5` and then skips to `7 - 7.5` and so on; it is not a continuous count.

Also, the values of the first coordinates are not equal, as those given in the example above, so the list may end up looking like

```
{{0.001, 3.1}, {0.005, 7.2}, {0.00001, 10.3}, {0.007, 13.4}}
```

which is still a correct result.

Comment: How are you defining elements that are close together?  Are you interested in `IntegerPart` or `Round` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume from your post the values of the second elements are to be grouped in ranges like [N,N+1), if so this should do what you want:

```
Gather[SortBy[yourListHere, First], IntegerPart[#1] == IntegerPart[#2] &][[All, 1]]
```

For a different way of looking at "close", this treats things within +/- .5 as "close", you can adjust as needed.

```
Gather[SortBy[yourListHere, First], (Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < .5) &][[All, 1]]
```

Beyond that, you'll need to better define what "close" means.

Comment: I just posted my edit a few seconds after yours and I guess we were thinking along the same line.

Comment: @RunnyKine: That's weird - your post was not even showing though older - unless the time is when it was started and the post doesn't show while being edited, but yes, like minds!

Comment: Thankx mate this worked perfectly, sorry for all the running round in circles, greatly appreciated though :)

Comment: @Colin: No worries. Welcome to *SE*, take the time to review the FAQ, it has help on posting code properly, and pointers to how to pose questions. This fora has a tremendous group of experts, the better you specify questions in the future, the more likely you'll get proper answers.

Comment: +1. I ended up deleting my answer since the edit was just too similar to yours.

Comment: @RunnyKine: Thanks for +, should have left post - your (cleaner) code showed another way of tackling it, valuable to readers even when the interpretations of method may very similar!

Answer (score 1):

When possible you should try to cast this kind of problem in a form that can be handled by `GatherBy`.  This is much faster than `Gather` with a custom comparator as I attempted to explain in: [Underlying Algorithms for List Manipulation Functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30328/underlying-algorithms-for-list-manipulation-functions/30331#30331). (Still unfinished, but at least `Gather` is covered.)  Also see [Checking for duplicates in sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30290/checking-for-duplicates-in-sublists/30293#30293) and the posts linked therein.

You can also efficiently, and often more conveniently, make use of [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html), though performance usually lags a bit behind `GatherBy`.

It is important to understand that `GatherBy` or `Sow`/`Reap` will produce slightly different results from `Gather` because they do not perform a full pairwise comparison; this is also the reason they are more efficient.  Likewise any other binning method will have better computational complexity than `Gather` or `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates` with a custom comparator, as the latter group all operate pairwise in that mode.

If your data is not conducive to regular bins as produced by `Round`, `Floor`, etc. (with a second parameter setting width) you may wish to do some analysis of the data beforehand to discover the "centers" of your data and then use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html), [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) etc. for binning.

If you give a larger data set and a clear description of your target I can probably provide you with a useful example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not terribly clear on what the criteria are, but here's another possible route which allows for defining criteria:

```
First@Sort[Cases[test, {_, x_} /; 
      IntegerPart[x] == #], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] & /@ {3, 7, 10, 13}
```

You'll have to replace `{3, 7, 10, 13}` with the complete list.  As alluded to in some of the comments, you may want `Round` instead, which can be done:

```
First@Sort[Cases[test, {_, x_} /; 
      Round[x] == #], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] & /@ {3, 7, 10, 13}
```

Which in this case yields the same result.