# Deleting isomorphic graphs efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to delete isomorphic graphs from a large list.
My solution is as follows:

```
DeleteIsoG1[gl_List]:= Module[{},
    DeleteDuplicates[gl,IsomorphicGraphQ]];
```

Unfortunately, it turns out very inefficient.
I'm aware that graph isomorphism problem belongs to NP.
I just need a relatively fast implementation in Mma.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

**Update:** I searched the forum. It looks that the performance can be improved by using other functions like `DeleteDuplicatesBy` or `GatherBy` instead of `DeleteDuplicates`.
But according to the observation of @Mr.Wizard [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30331/19614),
the behaviour of `GatherBy` is NOT a pairwise comparison.
Hence it seems that we need a new method to get around here.
The following is an implementation by using `Gather`.
But it is slower than the one using `DeleteDuplicates`.

```
DeleteIsoG2[gl_List] := Module[{},
    First /@ Gather[gl, IsomorphicGraphQ]];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`CanonicalGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalGraph.html) function in concert with `DeleteDuplicatesBy`:

```
DeleteIso[gs_List] := DeleteDuplicatesBy[gs, CanonicalGraph]
```

Comment: +1 Indeed, from docs: `CanonicalGraph` is often used to compare and match a graph to a large collection of graphs; isomorphic graphs have the same canonical graph.

Comment: @Pillsy Your solution works like a charm!